# Состояние "псюха" - как назвать литературно?

Tags: семантика

Нужно название, если есть, состояния человека, когда он совершает непроизвольное или неконтролируемое действие под влиянием внутренней причины: воспоминаний или каких-то собственных рассуждений, переживаний, эмоционального всплеска... Со злости там кулаком по столу ударит, закричит, клавиатурой в монитор швырнет...

О какой-то длительной психической неадекватности речи не идет, просто "психанул", "псюх" напал - и тут же успокоился.

///============================

Я нашел некий гипероним. Это какой-то *условный рефлекс*, но не патологический, а так сказать "квазипатологический".
Сюда же - склонность бледнеть или краснеть в тех или иных ситуациях, грызть ногти или карандаши, махать пуками при разговоре, глазом дергать, зубом цыкать, язык жевать...

Но мне нужно из всего этого понятийного поля выделить название для реакции, возникающей исключительно под действием внутреннего фактора и/или нейтрально внешнего.
Вот то, что называется ***"как вспомню - как вздрогну"***. Как вот такая реакция называется, если человек действительно дрожит от каких-то своих воспоминаний, размышлений и/или на внешний безобидный сигнал?!

Answer (score 3):

Психомоторное возбуждение, психомоторная реакция в рамках психологической нормы – ажитация. А еще слабее - аффект.

Comment: Да нет, ну что Вы. ПВ - это серьезный синдром, расстройство требующее длительного лечения. А тут в общем-то и патологии нет, ну просто неспровоцированное действо, разовое, и без особых последствий.

Comment: Не, говорят так и о здоровых людях.

Comment: Ну я в нескольких источниках посмотрел. Начиная с Вики.

Comment: Ажитация, посмотрите, это предпатология

Comment: Да, нет, спасибо, конечно, но это все весьма далеко. Там и состояние длительное и нарушения вегетативные... Вот смотрите. Сидит человек, чем-то занимается. Стихи пишет, 80-й левел в стрелялке проходит, задачку решает из теории функций комплексного переменного... Вдруг видит ошибку или не ту кнопку нажимает. Хлопает ладонью по столу, матюкнет разок. И всё. Здоров и адекватен, разве что окружающих напугает. В общем-то это состояние аффекта, вернее непроизвольное действие, в таком состоянии совершенное. Но мне хотелось бы, чтобы термин передавал, что причина внутренняя, эмоциональная и ерундовая.

Comment: С другой стороны, я ж не научную статью пишу, могу и простыми словами, описательно. Только покороче бы и без потери смысла..

Comment: Аффект – вполне... ну, да Вам виднее.

Answer (score 2):

Если речь о бурно протекающей реакции, может, что-то из этого: ярость, гнев, бешенство, истерия, исступление, безумие, буйство, запал, помрачение

Comment: Нет, Людмила, спасибо, но не то это все, Понятийное поле даже не то. Это какая-то внутренняя реакция, мгновенно возникающая, как чихание или там знаменитое жевание галстука одним политиком. А вообще не везет мне с таким вопросами. Несколько раз слово искал,  безуспешно. Не могу, видимо, сформулировать доходчиво.

Answer (score 2):

Я называю подобное проявление эмоций **блинство**, когда управляешь собой достаточно для того, чтобы не матюгаться, но недостаточно, чтобы не произнести эвфемизм. У кого самоконтроль похуже, тот и посерьёзнее себя выразит, но в целом самоконтроль не потеряет. Если это не научная статья, то слово может и подойти.

**Аффект** тоже можно использовать, но, правда, согласен, что тут нужно к нему добавить, что он *лёгкий,* так как из-за многочисленных детективов он ассоциируется с более сильным возбуждением.

Comment: Ну да, это понятно. ну тут нет того, что я назвал "как вспомню - так вздрогну". Для меня важно, что источник эмоций интровертный.

Answer (score 0):

Какая-то муха укусила. Чёрт дёрнул.

Comment: Вскипеть. Накипело.

Comment: Да почему просто не сказать "взорвался". Он вскипел/взорвался и со злости трам тарам тарам.